# traverse trough an object and add a new property/object?

Tags: javascript

consider this [JSON](https://jsfiddle.net/h567rxw3/) as a product and it could have infinite child products.

I need a function that loop through child products property and add a child to the right place:

```js
export const addChildProduct = (childTree, nestedChildIndex, updatedChild) => {
    let newChild = childTree;
    for (let i = 0; i < nestedChildIndex.length; i++) {
        newChild.childProducts[nestedChildIndex[i]].listOfNewCustomProduct[nestedChildIndex[i]];
    }
    newChild.childProducts === null
        ? (newChild.childProducts = Array.of(updatedChild))
        : newChild.childProducts.push(updatedChild);
    return newChild;
};
```

**for better understanding:**

`childTree` is the main/first `childProduct` array of the product.

`nestedChildIndex` is the array of indexes that determines how deep should I go inside `childProducts`, it's something like this: `['0', '0']` says that in the child products I should go to `index 0` of that and then inside `childProducts` of `index 0`, I should go into index 0 (hope you didn't confuse)

and `updatedChild` is the new child object I need to add. (I get that from a form but format is the same as others)

so how can I alter this loop to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

I manage the issue by altering the code like so:

```js
export const addChildProduct = (childTree, nestedChildIndex, updatedChild) => {
    let newChild = childTree;
    for (let i = 0; i < nestedChildIndex.length; i++) {
        newChild = newChild.childProducts[nestedChildIndex[i]].listOfNewCustomProduct[nestedChildIndex[i]];
    }
    newChild.childProducts === null
        ? (newChild.childProducts = Array.of(updatedChild))
        : newChild.childProducts.push(updatedChild);

    return {...childTree, childProducts: newChild};
};
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. it will only work in one case when the new updatedChild is added in the parent level itself, in all other case this will fail.
Actually even in that case it will not work as it was not needed, it would require nestedChildIndex to be empty.

Comment: @vaira it worked just as expected. you don't understand the question well.

Comment: this code will never work, the only thing this will do is if you have an inner nested child you had just updated it by bring it to top-level, which I am certain is not the desired behavior.

Answer (score -1):

You have missed reassigning the newChild with inner loops

```
 for (let i = 0; i < nestedChildIndex.length; i++) {
        newChild = newChild.childProducts[nestedChildIndex[i]].listOfNewCustomProduct[nestedChildIndex[i]];
    }
```

Comment: yes, I tried that but I need to return the whole product with new child added. not only that new child.

Comment: @EshgheCode Then in the last line replace  ' return newChild;' with ' return childTree;'

Comment: then what is the purpose of that loop? :)) 
I loop through `childTree` to add a new child with that loop if I return that then its the same one I pass to the loop with no change.

Comment: @EshgheCode you seems to not understand how pass-by reference works, I would suggest to read a bit about it.
Second, there is no loop in your code, there is only 'for' operator iteration, where you are going inside the tree structure product, you are not creating a loop.
You are adding value inside the ChildTree, you don't even need to return anything as its will get updated.